# Restrict Infinispan Cache to add multiple Nodes in a Cluster

Tags: java, jboss, infinispan, jgroups

I am using Infinispan cache in Jboss for my java project.
I have two nodes of Jboss running on different machines. I have successfully configure my infinispan cache which replicate their data between two nodes.
Below is my infinispan cache configuration:

```
GlobalConfigurationBuilder global = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder();
JChannel jchannel = new JChannel();
JGroupsTransport transport = new JGroupsTransport(jchannel);
global.transport().transport(transport);
manager = new DefaultCacheManager(global.build());
ConfigurationBuilder c = new ConfigurationBuilder();
c.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC).hash().numOwners(numOwners).numSegments(numSegments).capacityFactor(capacityFactor).build();
c.invocationBatching().enable();
c.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL).lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC);
manager.defineConfiguration(DIST, c.build());
```

but the problem is whenever i used above configuration its automatically detect all nodes and add it to the cluster which is i don't want. How can i restrict this; not to add all nodes in a cluster.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

**offtopic**: Infinispan creates the `JChannel` for you if you don't want to create and manage it yourself.
Use `GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()`.
You can find the Infinispan's configuration here: https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#cluster_transport

To solve your issue, you need to change the JGroups configuration. If you are using `UDP`+`PING` combination (most likely), to create separated clusters just change the `UDP` `mcast_addr` and/or `mcast_port` attributes.

Check the JGroups' documentation for more info: http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#DiscoveryProtocols

Comment: Thank you for you comment. I did this before, changed the mcast_addr of both nodes but no luck. 
Btw i have solved this issue by using cluster name.

manager = new DefaultCacheManager(GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder()
.transport().nodeName(nodeName).clusterName(cacheClusterName)
.build());

When both machines are on same network they send messages to one another but no one will make cluster until they found the same clusterName.

Comment: @FasihUrRehman setting a different cluster name works, but when using replicated caches with a UDP transport, all nodes have to receive the multicast messages from the other clusters and discard them. Having a different mcast_addr and mcast_port for each cluster is cheaper, because nodes only receive messages from their cluster, there is no extra work for messages from other clusters.

Comment: @DanBerindei I got your point here, but my scenario is I have two application servers on each application server I have 2 different applications deployed which have their own cache. So what I want is to clustering between 2 application servers of each application.

So for that I guess cluster name will help me for this scenario, but I am receiving below messages,

Comment: [jgroups-24,losci_qa-node-29683] - JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster losce_qa (our cluster is losci_qa). Sender was 076a2e56-d727-abed-0f78-4e8399bc74c1 (received 34 identical messages from 076a2e56-d727-abed-0f78-4e8399bc74c1 in the last 60006 ms)

Comment: (jgroups-21,losce_qa-node-35576) JGRP000012: discarded message from different cluster losci_qa (our cluster is losce_qa). Sender was 6ccf101a-1a0c-b659-a2f2-673b2f3d52f0 (received 33 identical messages from 6ccf101a-1a0c-b659-a2f2-673b2f3d52f0 in the last 60007 ms)

Comment: @FasihUrRehman that's exactly what I was talking about. If you configure a different mcast_addr for each cluster, the multicast messages only reach their intended destinations. If you configure the same mcast_addr and a different cluster name, all nodes receive all messages. The receivers discard message with a different cluster name and write message `JGRP000012` to the log.

Comment: @DanBerindei yes ur right! Actually I'm using Jboss Application server and in Jboss I have a socket binding in its standalone-ha.xml (configuration) file *jgroups-udp* which is using one mcast_addr. 
So now, I used the above configurations add the udp.xml in JChannel and change the mcast_addr for both the applications, and now messages are not appearing anymore in logs.